# When closing a tkinter window, it's hidden, but persists

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

It's a problem because I need to open and close windows as part of the program's function. By the windows persisting (I can select them from the 'Window' menu), they take up more and more memory as the program is used.

I'm using Python 3.6 on MacOS High Sierra.

Is there a way to make the windows actually destroy?

Example program where I would like to destroy the sub window:

```
import tkinter as tk

def subWindow():
  top = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", command=subWindow)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Non-working example using .destroy():

```
import tkinter as tk

def subWindow():
  top = tk.Toplevel(root)
  top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", top.destroy())

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", command=subWindow)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Traceback on pressing the "New Window" button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 5, in subWindow
    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", top.destroy())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1959, in wm_protocol
    'wm', 'protocol', self._w, name, command)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"
```

Another example that doesn't throw an exception, but still doesn't cause the sub window to be destroyed:

```
import tkinter as tk

def subWindow():
  top = tk.Toplevel(root)

  def closeSubWindow():
    top.destroy()

  top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeSubWindow)

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", command=subWindow)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like the full traceback.

Comment: Where exactly do you use `destroy` and what exactly do you want to close?

Comment: calling `destroy()` on the instance of a window is exactly how you do it.  Please show what you tried. Most likely what is happening is that you're saving the window to a _local_ variable, which only lasts until the function returns.

Comment: I failed to recreate where destroy() made no difference, so I must have had another bug. I have added an example where I try unsuccessfully to use destroy() to close the sub window. @BryanOakley I see what you're saying, but I want to be able to open any number of identical sub windows, so I can't figure out how I would make the Toplevel variable global.

Comment: It is still pretty unclear _when_ you want the toplevel to be destroyed. What makes you think it causes a memory leak?

Comment: If you want to have identically customized `Toplevel` wouldn't creating a class inheriting from it be a better way?

Comment: I don't see it as a memory leak as such. I have followed the memory usage in Activity Monitor. Since the windows are only hidden and not destroyed by clicking X, they still take up memory. Would a class be better - I don't know, would it fix the problem?

Comment: What is the proof that you think windows _aren't_ destroyed, they're visible after using default X button?

Comment: They are hidden, but still accessible from Window in the menu bar. I can select each window making it reappear with the same content. So clearly they are not destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the secondary window which is created by the method, it *does* get `destroy`ed if it's closed however by default you close any window. If you want to see for yourself, try adding:

```
print(root.winfo_children())
```

that lists the widgets that are direct children to `root`, which the `Toplevel` you created is a member of, as the very last line to `subWindow`.

Further `window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)` calls the `callback` when the default closing window protocol is ongoing, such as click the X button, or <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd>. It can be used to ask user things such as: *"Do you really want to close?"* before closing the window. Though, when you close a window regularly, it is *supposed to be destroyed* anyway, which means that while `top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeSubWindow)` doesn't raise an error, it is supposed to be redundant, unless the default behavior is overwritten somehow.

While the above may be true, as Bryan points out in the comments, the reference to the created `Toplevel`, `top` is a *local* name, which has no meaning outside `subWindow` method.